# Создание SharpDX Control

Tags: winforms, usercontrol, 2d, sharpdx

Доброго времени суток? 
Продолжаю изучать **SharpDX** и возникла небольшая сложность при создании своего **2D** контрола для *WinForms*, а именно туплю в моменте использования методов класса **RenderTarget** (таких как, *DrawRectangle*, *DrawEllipse* и др.).
Прошу помощи в виде, хотя бы, направления куда копать.
Версия SharpDX - 2.6.2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Direct3D10;


namespace WFDXControl
{
  using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D10.Device;
  using Factory2D = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory;
  using Buffer = SharpDX.Direct3D10.Buffer;
  using DriverType = SharpDX.Direct3D10.DriverType;


  public partial class DxControl : UserControl
  {
    private Device device;
    private Factory2D factory2d;
    private SwapChain swapChain;    

    public RenderTargetView renderTargetView;

    public IntPtr FormHandle;

    //private bool IsInitialized = false;

    private Color4 clearColor = SharpDX.Color.SkyBlue;
    public Color4 ClearColor
    {
      get { return clearColor; }
      set { clearColor = value; }
    }

    public Factory2D GetFactory()
    {
      return factory2d;
    }

    public DxControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      InitializeGraphics();
    }

    private void InitializeGraphics()
    {
      //настройка цепи
      SwapChainDescription swapChainDescription = new SwapChainDescription()
      {
        BufferCount = 1,
        Flags = SwapChainFlags.None,
        IsWindowed = true,
        ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(
          this.ClientSize.Width,
          this.ClientSize.Height,
          new Rational(60, 1),
          Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
        OutputHandle = this.Handle,//FormHandle,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
        Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
      };

      //создание устройства и цепи
      Device.CreateWithSwapChain(
        DriverType.Hardware,
        DeviceCreationFlags.None,
        swapChainDescription,
        out device,
        out swapChain
        );

      using (Texture2D backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0))
      {
        factory2d = new Factory2D(FactoryType.SingleThreaded, DebugLevel.Information);
        renderTargetView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);
      }
      //this.IsInitialized = true;
    }

    public void ClearRenderTarget(SharpDX.Color4 clearColor)
    {
      device.ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, clearColor);
    }

    public void Present()
    {
      swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена (не такой уж и было проблемой).

После инициализации *device* и *swapchain* создал *RenderTarget*(а не *RenderTargetView*) и каждому объекту, который подвергался рендерингу, тупо передавал ссылку на этот *RenderTarget*, и в методе Render() этого объекта использовал все нужные методы класса *RenderTarget*.